# Batch file to set the position of the curser on windows 7 OS. How?

Tags: windows, batch-file, screen

is it possible to make a batch file that sets the position of the mouse/curser to an (x,y) coordinate on the screen? and if so, then is it possible to click on something that is in that position? Any ideas would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: Chances are, there's a better way to do whatever you're trying to accomplish here. Automating user interaction (like clicking on something displayed on the screen) is difficult because as soon as whatever UI element it is gets moved or something covers it, your batch file stops working (or worse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and Yes.

You can't place the cursor at Position X,Y with pure batch, but you can replace the cursor to the home position in one line, and then you can rewrite the content.

For detecting mouse clicks with batch you need an external tool.

Try a look at [Lingubender Tan's Batch tools](http://www.lingubender.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=110)

**EDIT:** You **can** place the cursor with pure batch to the home postion, but I need the help of the user, *till now*.

Comment: I found that you can get the mouse coordinates with this ultra complicated batch-file: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1067 (A Tic-Tac-Toe Batch Game that uses mouse clicks...) or http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1062

Comment: But it isn't batch, it creates an executable exe file

Comment: (using Wscript/Cscript) I know, but it does it quickly and efficiently :D, its still pretty cool!

Answer (score 1):

No. You would have to have a seperate executable to do this for you.

It may be possible in VBScript.

P.S. If you're interesting in automating tasks I'd download something like a mouse recorder for something simple like that. If you're automating more complicated tasks, give a shot at Autoit.

Comment: ok how would you do it using vbscript? also, could you recommend a good tutorial for vbscript (im assuming vbscript is written in visual basic?)

Comment: i am not interested in automating tasks, i was just wondering if it was possible, ive seen a few custom programs for batch that do it, but again, i have no clue how to configure/setup custom commands/programs to work inside the command line...

Comment: VBscript is a "more extended" version of batch to most people. You can set datatypes, do more things, you can log the person out, you can make things run at certain times, heck, people have coded viruses in them (don't get any ideas..) Anyway, it's possible. You just have to have a seperate program do it for you. Batch 'programs' are really just 'scripts' that reads a file line by line. You can actually take (some) batch scripts, and type them in the command line, and they will have the same effect as if you ran the script. All batch is doing is running programs. Seriously, that's it!

Comment: Ok since ive posted this ive learned alot about vbscript, and python. So is it possible to accomplish this by means of a python script or vbs? If so , could you post an example to get me started! Thanks!